# How can I reference library project in an Android Test-Project (ant build)

Tags: android, testing, ant, jenkins, robotium

There are 3 projects:

1. Main project
2. A library project (ActionBarSherlock) referenced by main
3. A robotium test project.

These three projects are checked out by Jenkins into 3 folders in the workspace.

However, the Robotium test project cannot reference the library project:

- if only standard "android update test-project" is used, then the test project won't compile because it **indirectly** references the library project

  ```
  [javac] /home/jenkins_test/test/src/com/**********/test/core/**********TestCase.java:15: cannot access                com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
  [javac] class file for com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity not found
  [javac]             ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Home> {
  [javac]                                             ^
  [javac] /home/jenkins_test/test/src/com/**********/test/core/**********TestCase.java:55: cannot find symbol
  [javac] symbol  : constructor Solo(android.app.Instrumentation,com.**********.activity.Home)
  [javac] location: class com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
  [javac]             solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
  [javac]                    ^
  ```
- "android update test-project" does not have --library flag support
- if android.library.reference.1=../ActionBarSherlock is added to the test project's project.properties, then the test project can compile but at run time it will complain the main activity's class is not found (NoClassDefFoundError)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this fails with ant but tests can be built and run by Eclipse. The only thing you should take into account is checking the robotium library in ***Java Build Path -> Order and Export*** in your test project

[image]

and also check that your library project is **NOT** referenced in the test project's properties

[image]

If you want to test the library project *separately* you can follow the instructions described in [android: testing library projects](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2012/04/android-testing-library-projects.html).

I know this may not be the solution because you are using Jenkins, but at least it will let you start from solid ground.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably I have to run the tests manually for now. It would be nice to run it on Jenkins without manual interaction.